# If physical memory maps on RAM and virtual memory on hard disk where does logical memory do the mapping?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, memory-address

As what I read page size in both logical and physical memory is same and overall logical memory is bigger but where is it stored?

Answer (score 0):

Logical/virtual memory: is memory which a process uses for its use. this is not actual memory but abstraction which is called virtual memory. virtual memory is a mechanism used by usually all OS to manage actual Physical memory.

Now lets say your system has 4 GB RAM. In theory all your processes (lets say 100) can have 4GB RAM at a time. This is responsibility of MMU (memory management Unit) to give processes only that memory which they actually use to store their data. when a process make memory reference it uses only virtual address which contains nothing but it is a address. MMU takes this address and translates it into physical address where data is stored. MMU uses page table for this purpose. So logical memory which is also called virtual memory is stored no where. This memory is just set of addresses used to access actual memmory i.e. RAM

All this is basics of Virtual memory.

Comment: But page size in logical memory is as big as frame size in physical memory, isn't it? Where is that stored?

Comment: yes both have same size for ease of implementation. Just try to understand:  int x=0; will be stored in RAM, Virtual memory is a mechanism to reach that place where it is stored nothing more nothing less :)

Answer (score 0):

it is not necessary that entire physical memory will entirely will map to ram.
in embedded world every system on chip has its own memory map . so on a system bus of 32 bit you can generate 4 gb addresses. now it up to the vendor of soc to decide what memory range to give for ram , there are other component also in system need to addressed. 
So physical memory can be mainly categorized in.
1. Device memory (physical memory to access peripheral)
2. Normal Memory (ram).
usually on 32 bit system maximum ram is 3gb , 4gb its entire physical memory map.that is what you were saying that virtual memory pages stored in hard disk.

Now here we comes to virtual memory / logical memory.
 it is again on 32 bit system you can have maximum of 4gb virtual address space. Your ram could be only 512 kb.

here i want to explain what is logical memory , it is part of virtual address space itself but it can be directly mapped by an offset, it is one to one mapped , so mapping will be always present  for logical memory  , usually this logical memory  comes under kernel space. we used to divide the entire 4gb memory to a ratio of 1:3, 1 gb part of virtual address space for kernel space and 3gb is part of user space.

So here we have little amount of ram as compare to 3gb virtual address space and how we  manage it by using individual page table foe each process.every time we don't need to keep pages for every process in ram so pages belong to process which are not running can be moved to swap which is a secondary storage.